# libcurl and failed downloading

Tags: c++, libcurl

I run multiple downloads with curl

```
curl_multi_perform(multi_handle, &still_running);
```

I need to detect if the connection fails during the downloading. What is the best way to do it. Is it possible/correct to use CURLOPT_TIMEOUT somehow in this way?

Thanks